# Typecasting in java

Tags: java

```
int n ;
n= (int)( javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"enter a 3 digit no."));
```

Why does the above gives error[required int, found string] and the below one works fine ?

```
int n ;
n= Integer.parseInt( javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"enter a 3 digit no."));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) doesn't use casting but rather a simple algorithm to interpret the digits in the string as a number. Casting is done by the JVM directly on the primitive value or the compiler on the object reference. It can turn `4.5` into `4` (*type conversion* as it changes the underlying value) and `ArrayList` into `List` (*reference casting* as it doesn't modify the instance), but it cannot [parse or format numbers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/converting.html) natively.

Comment: You cannot cast an `int` to a `boolean`.

Answer (score 8):

Type casting is not type conversion, don't confuse the terms. Casting means reinterpreting the same binary representation as a value of another type. In Java there **are** conversions, but only between primitive numeric values. String is a reference type, I guess you know that.

Answer (score 1):

Java only lets you make valid casts, i.e. ones it knows how to make. Casting a string to an int is nonsensical; parsing it is not.